# Return an Observable of String after a call to an API that returns a Single

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am new to Rx and in mid of a somewhat complex situation for a newbie.

I have a situation where I am calling a function to say doSomething. In doSomething I am making an API call called apiCall. This API returns a single. I actually don't want to use this single result. The API call triggers a mechanism which sends an observable stream of Strings (this observable is returned by `fnCallreturnsAnObservableStreamOfString`) and I need to return that from the fun `doSomething`

Currently I am using `flatMapObservable`, it is compiling fine but its not working correctly.

```
override fun doSomething(firstParam: Int, secondParam: Int) : Observable<String> =
        apiCall(firstParam,secondParam).flatMapObservable{ fnCallreturnsAnObservableStreamOfString()}
```

Can someone please help me to do this correctly.

Edit:-

The problem with the code is on calling doSomething fnCallreturnsAnObservableStreamOfString() is not being called.

Comment: Can you share more code or let us know what exactly not working

Comment: Can you show us please where your observable is subscribed?